# Where can I find documentation on OpenSSL.Net

Tags: c#, openssl

I've found DLL's ok, but I'm having trouble finding documentation.

I want to use C# to decrypt a string of text using a private RSA key. Documentation on OpenSSL.Net would be great, information on how to do this in particular would be amazing!

The string itself was in Base64, and my private key is stored in a *.pem file. My final method is below, based on LOSTCODER's answer:

```
public string Decrypt(string textToDecrypt)
{
    byte[] payLoad = Convert.FromBase64String(textToDecrypt);

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("pemfilelocation.pem");
    string privateKey = sr.ReadToEnd();

    using (var key = CryptoKey.FromPrivateKey(privateKey, "myprivatekey"))
    {
        using (var rsa = key.GetRSA())
        {
            payLoad = rsa.PrivateDecrypt(payLoad, RSA.Padding.PKCS1);
        }
    }

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(payLoad);
}
```

Comment: take a look at http://openssl-net.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Glad if it helped :) But I would rather refactor it to keep the IO functionality out. Infact you ought to read the .pem file just once, not everytime  you decrypt some text.

Comment: Of course, I have made my private key a private readonly string in my class then added the IO functionality to my constructor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following routine to decrypt a byte[] using RSA private key. If you want to pass your encrypted 'string of text', use `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()` to convert it to a byte[] (text is assumed to be ASCII encoded).

```
private static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] payLoad, string privateKey)
{
    using (var key = OpenSSL.Crypto.CryptoKey.FromPrivateKey(privateKey, null))
    {
        using (var rsa = key.GetRSA())
        {
            return rsa.PrivateDecrypt(payLoad, OpenSSL.Crypto.RSA.Padding.PKCS1);
        }
    }
}
```